# How to convert a character matrix to a numeric data.frame

Tags: r, matrix

I have a character `matrix` and a character `data.table`. When I merge them a `data.frame` is created but the `character` classes all converted to `factor`s which I wanted to avoid. Is there a way to avoid it?

```
df.new<-merge(matrix, df, by= col1)
```

I tried to turn the `character` `matrix` to `numeric` beforehand but then I lost the dimensions of the `matrix`.

```
num.matrix<- sapply(matrix, as.numeric)
```

Is there a neat way to handle such a situation?

Comment: You can coerce a matrix to numeric like this: `m <- matrix(c("1", "a"), 2); mode(m) <- "double"`

Comment: or `m[] <- as.numeric(m)`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert matrix into data.table with argument stringsAsFactors = FALSE. See below:

```
library(data.table)
m <- matrix(letters[1:9], ncol = 3)
df <- data.table(V1 = letters[1:3], a = letters[4:6], b = letters[7:9])
foobar <- merge(as.data.table(m, stringsAsFactors = FALSE), df)
str(foobar)
```

Output:

```
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ V1: chr  "a" "b" "c"
 $ V2: chr  "d" "e" "f"
 $ V3: chr  "g" "h" "i"
 $ a : chr  "d" "e" "f"
 $ b : chr  "g" "h" "i"
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
 - attr(*, "sorted")= chr "V1"
```